# How insert variables into SQL query in Python?

Tags: python

I want to get data from the SQL database, however, sometimes the filter condition in SQL query should be changed (dates).

Python code is working when filters of the dates are inside query:

```
import vertica_python

conn_info = {'host': 'unreachable.server.com',
             'port': 888,
             'user': 'some_user',
             'password': 'some_password',
             'database': 'a_database',
             'backup_server_node': ['123.456.789.123', 'invalid.com', ('10.20.82.77', 6000)]}
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)

cur = connection.cursor()
start_date = '2020-06-25'
end_date = '2020-07-25'
cur.execute("""
SELECT price as price, volume as volume
FROM My_DB

WHERE START_TS >= '2020-06-25'
and START_TS <= '2020-07-25'
ORDER BY price
                """) 
df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
```

However, I want to replace dates with variables start_date and end_date
I tried following approaches with `format` and `f-type strings`, however there was an error (Query error).

```
cur.execute(f"""
SELECT price as price, volume as volume
FROM My_DB

WHERE START_TS >= {start_date }
and START_TS <= {end_date }
ORDER BY price
                """) 
df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
```

and

```
cur.execute("""
SELECT price as price, volume as volume
FROM My_DB

WHERE START_TS >= {}
and START_TS <= {}
ORDER BY price
                """.format(start_date ,end_date )) 
df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas-read-sql) with `params=(start_date ,end_date)` is better than building your SQL statement which leaves you open to SQL injection. Am on phone so cannot post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes to enclose your variables: `'{start_date }'` and `'{end_date }'`

```
cur.execute(f"""
SELECT price as price, volume as volume
FROM My_DB

WHERE START_TS >= '{start_date }'
and START_TS <= '{end_date }'
ORDER BY price
                """) 
df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid SQL injection

```py
connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)

start_date = '2020-06-25'
end_date = '2020-07-25'

# not sure about the %s placeholder; you may need to use ? instead
# the engine takes care of the quoting (if required) for you
sql = """
    SELECT price as price, volume as volume
    FROM My_DB

    WHERE START_TS >= %s
        AND START_TS <= %s
    ORDER BY price
    """

df = pd.readsql(sql, connection, params=(start_date, end_date))
```